# React Component Chart from API Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am been successful in accessing the data from an API into the component. But because of the nature of the structure of the code I cannot pass values to the chart (Chart.js) in the render() method. Which is where I am able to access the component state data amongst which is the new data imported from an API.

I have tried a great many things over the past two days without success. I would be happy to even have a hint of how to approach the problem. Please find the code below.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Row, Col, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, Button } from "shards-react";

import Chart from "../../utils/chart";

const API = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&aggregrate=168&limit=168&api_key=90f934173fe9dd81d5acc53f0a9a6c56a9ffcce322e24e722fa842deeff3601b'

let staticPrices = [20500,1800,1320,1180,240,320,230,650,590,1200,750,940,1420,1200,960,1450,1820,2800,2102,1920,3920,3202,3140,2800,3200,3200,3400,2910,3100,4250];



class BtcOverview extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {

      fetchingData: true,
      priceData : null
    }

  }


  componentDidMount() {

  const getPrices = () => {
      fetch(API)
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(marketData => {

          let intPriceData = [];

          for (let number in marketData.Data){
            intPriceData.push(marketData.Data[number].close)
          };


          this.setState({
            priceData: intPriceData,
            fetchingData: false,
          })
        })
     }


    const BtcChart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, {
      type: "LineWithLine",
      data: this.props.chartData,
      options: chartOptions
    });


    // Render the chart.
    BtcChart.render();
  }

  render() {

    const { title } = this.props;
    return (
      <Card small className="h-100">
        <CardHeader className="border-bottom">
          <h6 className="m-0">{title}</h6>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardBody className="pt-0">
          <canvas
            height="160"
            ref={this.canvasRef}
            style={{ maxWidth: "100% !important" }}
          />
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    );

  }
}

BtcOverview.propTypes = {

  title: PropTypes.string,
  chartData: PropTypes.object,
  chartOptions: PropTypes.object
};



BtcOverview.defaultProps = {
  title: "BITCOIN",
  chartData: {
    labels: Array.from(new Array(30), (_, i) => (i === 0 ? 1 : i)),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "USD",
        fill: "start",
        data: staticPrices,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,123,255,0.1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0,123,255,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,123,255)",
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 3
      }
    ]
  }
};

export default BtcOverview;
```

The chart is currently rendering some static data that was included with the component for demonstration purposes.

Forgive my pasting of so much code and not narrowing down the issue more. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How does Char component look? I see you made your own Chart.

First of all your structure looks weird. Looks like you are trying to render chart component outside of render method inside which you passed all the other components. Why? How does BtcChart.render method look like? 
Second, you dont have to make new array that you push values from the API. .map will do the job, here is my code, hopefully it works, i haven't tried it in project, but it is what i usually do.

```
  const getPrices = () => {
      fetch(API)
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(marketData => {
          this.setState({
            priceData: marketData.map(el => el.close),
            fetchingData: false,
          })
        })
     }
```

Comment: I have not been able to adapt your code snippet yet but I will work on it. However, with regards to the code structure choices. I did not put together the core code. The charts parent class can be found here - https://github.com/DesignRevision/shards-dashboard-react/blob/7288ef5c811acef6212428c45c660b70b6d0dd54/src/utils/chart.js .